# In chocolatey is it possible to pause download and installation of a package and continue later?

Tags: chocolatey

I want to install some big packages using chocolatey and I need a way to pause and resume installation or downloading of package process.
Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in Chocolatey today that would allow you to do this, no.  My suggestion would be to raise a Feature Request issue on the main Chocolatey [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco) with more details about exactly what you would like to have happen here, so that it can be discussed further.